# Image ResizableImageWithCapInsets resizing Mode not stretching image uniformly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an image view of size

```
CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30)
```

I have an image sized 50 x 50 Px. It contains an drawing at the centre of it. I wish to stretch this image to fit the imageView. I achieve this by the following

```
viewImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Then it stretches the image in all directions and looks ugly. Then I used the resizeImageWithCapInsets as the following

```
[placeHoldImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0, 1.0, 40.0, 40.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]
```

However this produces the following image

[image: What I get]

What I wish to change in this image is that the house symbol at the right bottom corner to be centred. This is the drawing of the image (50 x 50) which I dint want to get stretched.

Comment: Have you tried other content mode values, such as UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, etc?

Comment: Im using SDWebImage framework, which allows you to download the image you wish to display asynchronously. This is a placeholderImage. Hence I cannot change the mode from initial UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. The later content mode is required to display the photo, which may be out of bounds of the imageview. Please let me know if you need any details. I hope I'm clear

Comment: You can't do this with stretchable images. A stretchable image always stretches the center of the image, while leaving the edges unstretched. For the effect that you want, you'd need the opposite behavior.

Comment: Why don't you lay the house-image on top of a background image, then you can stretch the background image.

Comment: how about changing the content mode of the image view as you need it, UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill while displaying placeholder image, UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit after the photo is downloaded?